# Live USB faster than full install

Tags: 11.04, unity, live-cd, live-usb

When I run 11.04 from a USB flash drive, it works the way I suspect it should - quick and responsive. With a full install, on the other hand, I click the home button and I have to wait four seconds to see the dash (this is insane - I have a core i5). Same thing with alt+F2.

I've also tested the live USB on an older laptop with inferior specs and it still runs faster than my full install.

What's going on? How do I fix this?

Comment: Try creating a new user and seeing if the lag persists. If not, it is due to some settings, in which case the fix is to just create a new username for yourself, or reset your settings somehow.

Comment: I found this exact same behaviour. Well, I was running a Live CD session, but apart from that, I know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Go to CCSM (compiz Configuration Settings Manager) then go to the OpenGL plug in and then uncheck Sync to Vblank.

Then go back and on the Composite plug in uncheck Detect Refresh Rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Unity settings in CCSM. The "Dash Blur" setting was set to "Static Blur". Changing that back to "No Blur" fixes the issue. I suppose this is why it's under the "Experimental" tab.

By the way, the list of PCI devices was the same and I did not try disabling OpenGL because I don't want to disable all the plugins that use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the video drivers/configs on the final install. Maybe a live version doesn't do much config specific for your machine. Try to compare video drivers on both systems.

Run lspci then  look for Graphic Driver.

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is becouse of all live operating systems work on ramdisk and ramdisk is very much faster than hdd ssd and ofcourse usb flash disk.